# Cant connect to a SQL datasource in Visual Studio using Web Forms

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, webforms

I am attempting to populate a drop down list, and I think I am doing it the right way. I am using Web Forms on Visual Studio.I have my drop down list, and my databases set up correctly in the server explorer on Visual Studio 2015. Once I try and create a Sql data source (I'm using MySQl by the way) I get this error.
[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTnky.png) and I've watched videos on how to do this and I'm pretty sure I'm following the right instructions but don't know how to fix this error. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Unless you provide at least your code, nobody will be able to assist you.

Comment: Post your code and error message to your question, not to an external site. The SO search feature doesn't search external sites, and when your link expires your question will not make any sense. Post the code and error message as text, not as an image; we can't cut and paste images to a compiler.

Comment: There is no code yet. I just go to the data source and hit "test query". Didn't think I needed code at this point. Just to populate the drop down list @DmytroBogatov

Answer (score 0):

Check for connection string in web.config. I think its empty.

Comment: That Db wizard should write the connection string in config file.

Comment: There is the connection string in my config file.

Comment: Is it valid? Can you post it?